# how can i fill the gridview with dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my code :

```
    string aaa;
    aaa = Request.Params["aaa"];
    string strSel;
    if (aaa != "" && aaa != null)
    {
       // Response.Write("<script>alert('" + aaa + "');</script>");
        strSel = "Select * from inout where FName like '%" + aaa + "%'";

    }
    else
    {
        strSel = "Select * from inout";
    }
    Response.Write(strSel);
    string strProvider = "Server=(local);DataBase=AIS20060712101417;UID=sa;PWD=";
    Data0 ds= new Data0();
    SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(strProvider);
    MyConn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSel, MyConn);
    MyAdapter.Fill(ds,"inout");  
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

then the gridview is empty.

Comment: Did you verify (debugger) that the query returns any rows at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true ?

Try adding `ds.Tables[0]` as `DataSource`.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy dear......Try this one it works well for me

```
 using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        string str = "User ID=username;Password=password;Data Source=Test";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(str);
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from table_name";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd); 
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

And it's Done.Happy Coding with C#

Comment: LOLz , answering 2.7 Years Old post :D

Comment: No mettter how old is the posted question.........tell me dear if the answer is not correct.i am sharring what i know may be the questioner is no longer needed the answer but in future it will INSHALLAH save someone's time

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  My solution was to remove the "*" and manually include the column names.