# Pass table from DataSet as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm really new with C# and ASP.Net, I can say that i'm learning *over the road*. What i need to do is run an stored procedure and create an Excel file with the response. This is my code so far of the controller:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using ConfigurationSettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace NewSalesReport.Controllers
{    
public class NewSalesReportController : Controller
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string inline = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConectionString"];
            using (SqlConnection toConect = new SqlConnection(inline))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DaReport", toConect))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));

                    using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        adp.Fill(ds);
                        /*if (ds != null)
                        {
                            //Console.Write("It is not Empty");
                        } */


                    }

                }


            }

        }

        private void SetDataExcel(object result)
        {
            GridView grid = new GridView();
            grid.DataSource = result;
            StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);

            grid.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=reportExcel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            Response.Output.Write(strwritter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            strwritter.Dispose();
            htmltextwrtter.Dispose();
        }

        public ActionResult GetAprovedForPay(DateTime? fi = null, DateTime? ff = null)
        {
            var result = _repo.GetAprovedForPay(fi, ff);
            SetDataExcel(result);
            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

}

Someone is helping me with a few advices, and he told me that i need to pass the first table as a parameter: `ds.Tables[0]`, but he didn't explain how.

Also, when i run the compiler shows an error which says that i need a

> reference object for the field, method or property `Controller.Response`.

Someone can help me, please with this two issues? As i said, i'm new with this hole thing of .Net.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Why is there  `static void Main()` in your controller class?

Comment: What do you need to pass the `DataTable` to? Is there another method you need to write?

Comment: yes make it non-static

Comment: Thanx, so... i remove static void Main or just change for something like "public string..."?

Answer (score 1):

*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property* error occurred because you're calling `Controller.Response` from a method which has return type of `void` instead of `ActionResult`.

First, remove inner class `Program` and rename `Main()` method to other name (also remove `static` if necessary). Sounds like the code includes `Main()` method previously used in console/WinForms application, and you should change it to avoid confusion.

Second, remove `Response` usage and use `FileResult` to return file for download as in example below:

```
public FileResult SetDataExcel(object obj)
{
    GridView grid = new GridView();
    grid.AutoGeneratedColumns = true; // automatically generate all columns from data source
    grid.DataSource = result;
    StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);

    grid.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);

    string path = Server.MapPath("~/path/to/filename.xls");

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        sw.Write(strwriter.ToString());
    }

    var savedFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

    return File(savedFile, "application/ms-excel");
}
```

Finally, you can use redirection to call `SetDataExcel` which returns the file:

```
public ActionResult GetAprovedForPay(DateTime? fi = null, DateTime? ff = null)
{
    var result = _repo.GetAprovedForPay(fi, ff);
    return RedirectToAction("SetDataExcel", new { obj = result });   
}
```

**Note:** Regarding data binding for `GridView`, if `AutoGeneratedColumns` set to true then you can use `ds.Tables[0]` as data source (see the reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091130/how-can-i-fill-the-gridview-with-dataset)):

```
string inline = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConectionString"];
using (SqlConnection toConect = new SqlConnection(inline))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DaReport", toConect))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));

        using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);

            grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            grid.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, this is the explanation what i need

Comment: Hi, @Tetsuya I'm getting an error that says: "The 'grid' name does not exist on actual context", you know why?